# Make Blender usable on high resolution screen

Tags: interface, windows

The Blender UI elements are incredibly small by default on high resolution screens on Windows (15" UHD screen).  I found the Preferences -> System -> DPI setting which can be set up to 144.  This makes Blender usable, but still uncomfortable and difficult on the eyes.  Is there a way to make the UI elements even larger?

Comment: under that there is Virtual pixel mode choose : Double

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To make the UI elements even larger you can choose **Double** under the **Virtual Pixel mode**
this option is in **User_Preferences->system**
[image]

Comment: A combination of DPI and Double can really do the trick. My native DPI on my 4k 27" monitor is 164 dpi. I set virtual pixel mode to double and DPI: to half of 164, i.e. 82. So that 2 x 82 = 164. I wish you could go higher on DPI though.

Comment: This is obsolete by now ?

Answer (score 33):

Another thing that is very useful is to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the Middle Mouse Button to rescale various panels.  This is the same for the 3D Viewport when zooming in or out to view a model.  The Outliner Area is the only place I've found so far where this does not function yet.

[image]

By pressing the <kbd>HOME</kbd> key on your keyboard, you can reset the resized panels back to the original default size.

Comment: Neat trick. I can't figure out how to do this with the keypad on a Surface Book but I was able to do it with an Arc mouse by holding CTRL and "double-tap and holding" the scroll pad. Thanks. Maybe StackOverflow needs to add the ability to have multiple correct answers because both your answer and the answer from @Chebhou are two important pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: THANK-YOU! i can now avoid going blind between 4k and 2k res ! :)

Answer (score 16):

Hover the cursor over one of the panels and hit <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> keys on the keyboard to change the size of the font and UI elements.

Answer (score 10):

As of the latest version, the setting name has changed.
File > User Preferences
or CTRL ALT U

And the very first entry at the top:
Display: Scale
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In version 2.8 this setting is now under **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Interface** -> **Resolution Scale**

[image: Resolution Scale Setting Screenshot]

Comment: It would be cool that blender takes the value of gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor be default, so one doesn't have to search the option with a magnifier.