# How to modifiy interface font size?

Tags: interface

Absolutely new of Blender, I do have great difficulties to follow tutorials, because the size font appear on my screen 3840x2160 too much small, and I (myope) have to unwear glasses and approach the screen to read.
How I can change the font size of the interface ? 
I couldn't do by the usual Windows screen Tools.....

Many thanks...
Bruno

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/make-blender-usable-on-high-resolution-screen

Answer (score 9):

Just go into **User Preferences *[CTRL+ALT+U]***, then select the **Themes** tab, and then **Text Style** on the sidebar.

[image: Adjusting the font size in Blender]