# Why are my tool menus tiny? (pic)

Tags: windows, installation

[image: Picture of my screen]

I am using windows 10 on an ASUS laptop and the sidebars are miniscule. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Each view/panel is zoomable in Blender. So you can zoom in/out in the tools panel just like in the 3D view.

Comment: and easy to do with a control +/- and mouse over panel

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have high-dpi screen. If this is the case, see here: [Make Blender usable on high resolution screen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/make-blender-usable-on-high-resolution-screen).

In a nutshell, go to `Preferences` -> `System` -> `DPI`. Play around with the value until you are comfortable. If that isn't enough, see the link.

To actually answer your question: they are tiny, because they are fixed to a pixel size and your pixels are tiny.