# Increasing font size in the 3D view?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, customization

How can font size be increased in the 3D viewport? 
[image: edge length text in 3D view]

[image: object name in 3D view]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Blender usable on high resolution screen](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/make-blender-usable-on-high-resolution-screen)

Comment: Not sure why this is being VTC'd a year after it was asked.. Not a duplicate IMO, having the same answer does not make the question the same.

Comment: My issue was primarily to have dimension fonts to be bit bigger. But bigger DPI will lead to bigger UI entirely. Are there any other dimensioning tool that can be helpful in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know is to increase the DPI:

User Preferences >>> System >>> General >>> DPI

(but that will also change the size of all fonts in your interface)