# How to increase Font size in blender-3d (2.79)?

Tags: interface, customization

After the new update, how to increase the font size to be larger in blender 2.79?

Comment: question is not clear font size of what can u add a screenshot what font size u want to increase text or UI

Comment: [Make Blender usable on high resolution screen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27016/2217)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Blender usable on high resolution screen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/make-blender-usable-on-high-resolution-screen)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/UI): The user preferences now have a Display Scale setting in the Interface tab, to adjust the size of fonts and buttons relative to the automatically detected DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Make the change in small increments.
File->User Preferences->Interface Tab.
Display scale is set automatically to 1.00
Make small incremental changes 1.10,1.15....as you desire.
Save User settings.[image]